# My array keeps printing null. Improperly filled?

Tags: java, arrays, null

**I've looked at other questions asked, and most use splitting and I'm not using that, nor have they been appropriately answered based on my situation.** Practicing with Array, now trying to pull Strings from a file. Here is my Main Class

```
Scanner fileIn = null;  // Initializes fileIn to an empty object
  try
  {
     // Attempt to open the file
     FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("questions.dat");
     fileIn = new Scanner(file);
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
        // If the file could not be found, this code is executed
        // and then the program exits
     System.out.println("File not found.");
     System.exit(0);
  }

String line = "";
int i = 0;
String question[] = new String[5];

for(i=0; i < question.length; i++)
  {
     while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
     {
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        question[i] = fileIn.nextLine();

     }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question));
}
```

From some reason, when it prints question[] it prints [7, null, null, null, null]. I have no clue why. Is my Array not actually filled with the Strings?
Example String. **How many days in a week are there? seven. How many fingers do most people have? ten. This is the last string.** Where is the Program getting null from?

Comment: `questions[i] = line` would help. You are skipping a line by calling `nextLine()` twice as you currently are

Answer (score 4):

You have nested loops and you fill only very first element in your array:

```
for(i=0; i < question.length; i++)
  {
     while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
     {
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        question[i] = fileIn.nextLine();

     }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question));
}
```

You need to remove the inner loop:

```
for(i=0; i < question.length; i++)
  {
     if(fileIn.hasNextLine())
     {
        line = fileIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        question[i] = line;

     }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also building up on @kOner answer, this will work better

```
for(i=0; i < question.length && fileIn.hasNextLine(); i++)
{
    line = fileIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    question[i] = line;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(question));
```

Comment: Thanks, this one actually solved it. Much appreciated my friend.